# Sql Join statement retrieving name

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to retrieve the Name from EmployeeMaster and insert into LeaveCarryForwardTemp.. I wrote this query..  But its Returning a null value.. pls advice..

```
   (    
         @CreatedUserID as nvarchar(9)
        ,@CalendarYear as numeric(18, 0)    
   )
    AS

    BEGIN

    Select

        A.EmployeeID,B.Name  as EmpName             
        From HRLeaveCarryForwardTemp A
        Join HREmployeeMaster B On A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
        Where A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID

        Delete dbo.HrLeaveCarryForwardTemp
        Where UserID = @CreatedUserID 

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[HrLeaveCarryForwardTemp]
           ( [UserID]
            ,[EmployeeID]
            ,[CalendarYear]
            ,[LeaveCarryForward]
            ,[Status]
            )
        Select 
             @CreatedUserID             
            ,[EmployeeID]
            ,@CalendarYear
            ,[LeaveCarryForward]
            ,[Status]           
        From dbo.[HRLeaveCarryForward]
        Where CalendarYear =@CalendarYear

    END
```

Comment: So, your select statement, which is from HRLeaveCarryForwardTemp and HREmployeeMaster, is to check to see if any EmployeeID's are in the Temp table?  Also, I don't see anywhere in here where you are inserting the Name value from EmployeeMaster into the Temp table.  The select references it, but does nothing further.

Comment: thats the thing.. I need to insert the name value in HrLeaveCarryForwardTemp table.. But HRLeaveCarryForward Does not have the Name attribute..

Answer (score 0):

You are joining HRLeaveCarryForwardTemp with HREmployeeMaster, and inserting from HRLeaveCarryForward table..??

Comment: yes i am joining HRLeaveCarryForward with HREmployeeMaster.. Retrieve the name to insert into HRLeaveCarryForwardTemp table..

Answer (score 0):

So you will have to save the Name or Id in a variable, and pass the variable to Insert query,
Like below...

```
DECLARE @EmpID int

Select  @EmpID = A.EmployeeID
        From HRLeaveCarryForwardTemp A
        Join HREmployeeMaster B On A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
        Where A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
```

-- Or if you want Name then

```
Declare @EmpName varchar(50)

Select  @EmpName = B.Name 
        From HRLeaveCarryForwardTemp A
        Join HREmployeeMaster B On A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
        Where A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
```

Now pass the variable according to your requirements to Insert query...